# [XNA/MonoGame]Project a 3d vector to 2d screen

Tags: c#, vector, 3d, xna

I recognized that the method "Project" which can be found in the class viewport returns a three-dimensional vector which makes sense.( To store the depth).

Is this .Z value unnecessary for representing 3d on a 2-dimenional screen or do I have to devide the X and Y values of the resulting vector by the Z value?

And does XNA actually use the same method to represent 3d a point in 2d?

I thank You in advance and look forward for constructive answers.